# Select random rows from few tables (1 row per 1 table)

Tags: mysql

I have one problem to solve

I have for example 2 or more tables in db

i need to select random row, 1 per each table

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to select a random row from a table.  The easiest (which works well on small tables) is:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

If all your tables have the same columns, you can combine the results from multiple such queries using `union all`.  You could also combine the rows into one mega-row using `cross join`.